# Как сделать корректное отображение контекта на страницах?

Tags: django

Изучаю Django, не знаю как правильно отобразить контекст, чтобы он не повторялся каждый раз, а использовался только в одном html коде.

Есть главная html страница students.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'general/css/general.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h4>Главная • {% block page %}{% endblock %}</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ block.super }}
        {% block content %}
    <div class="block" STYLE="border: 2px solid darkgray; padding-right: 10px;">
        ***<h4>{{ full_name }}</h4>***
        <p>СТУДЕНТ</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'students-get-id' %}">ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ID</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'students-progress' %}">УСПЕВАЕМОСТЬ</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'students-notification' %}">УВЕДОМЛЕНИЯ</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'students-about' %}">О СЕБЕ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button style="width: 107%">ВЫЙТИ</button>
    </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Идёт вызов {{ full_name }} (выделил)

Данный файл является как главный, другие просто наследуются, допустим возьму один из них - get_id.html

```
{% extends 'general/students.html' %}

{% block title %}{% block page %}Получение ID{% endblock %}{% endblock %}

{% block content  %}
<div class="block" STYLE="padding-right: 150px; padding-bottom: 114px; border: 2px solid darkgray;">
    <h4>Информация</h4>
    <button>ПОЛУЧИТЬ КОД</button>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Запуская сервер и переходя по ссылке этой html страницы, full_name не отображается, просто пустота

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('work-check/', views.Students.get_id, name="teacher-work-check"),
    path('work-list/', views.Students.notification, name="teacher-work-list"),
    path('about/', views.Students.about, name="teacher-about"),

    path('get-id/', views.Students.get_id, name="students-get-id"),
    path('notification/', views.Students.notification, name="students-notification"),
    path('about/', views.Students.about, name="students-about"),
    path('progress/', views.Students.progress, name="students-progress"),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse


def home_teacher(request):
    return render(request, template_name='general/teacher/teacher.html')


user_data = {
    'full_name': "ИВАНОВ И.П."
}


class Teacher:

    def work_check(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/get_id.html', context=user_data)

    def work_list(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/notification.html', context=user_data)

    def about(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/teacher/about.html', context=user_data)


class Students:

    def students(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students.html', context=user_data)

    def get_id(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/get_id.html')

    def notification(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/notification.html')

    def progress(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/progress.html')

    def about(request):
        return render(request, template_name='general/students/about.html')
```

Запуская сервер и переходя по ссылке этой html страницы, full_name не отображается, просто пустота